# How to connect to PEAP MSCHAPv2 Wi-Fi using system certificates in Android 8.0 Oreo?

Tags: wi-fi, 8.0-oreo

This is in followup to a similar question about Android 7.1
[How to connect to PEAP MSCHAPv2 Wi-Fi using system certificates in Android 7.1 Nougat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162927/how-to-connect-to-peap-mschapv2-wi-fi-using-system-certificates-in-android-7-1-n)

In there is said:
"Android 7.1 has introduced some changes to Wi-Fi connection interface. In 6.0, when selecting PEAP MSCHAPv2 in Wi-Fi connection interface, there were no CA certificates available (unless some had been installed). In 7.1 one can Use system sertificates and Domain input field appears."

But in 8.0 it seems its back to no certificates, just "Select CA certificate" and "none" and hitting "Select CA Certificate" does not do anything, and it doesnt let you continue with the setup.

Anyone know how to connect to a PEAP MSCHAPv2 Wi-Fi using a certificate in 8.0?
I've exported the cert from a windows machine connected to it and imported it as a user certificate for wifi, and still nothing happens when you click "Select CA certificate".

Thank you!